# Javascript or JQuery to write to all rows of a specified column index in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that needs to put OK in Status column of table `tblItem` which is empty initially. How do I do that in Javascript or JQuery?

Table id: `tblItem`

```
Id    Item    Price   Status
1     A       15
2     B       20
2     B       25
```

When button pressed, table should be like this:

```
Id    Item    Price   Status
1     A       15      OK
2     B       20      OK
2     B       25      OK
```

Comment: you want this: `document.getElementById("tblItem").innerHTML("OK");` for every row, probably want an if, else statement for "OK" or "" and you should put this in an event handler for onclick.

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery is, in fact, javascript

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('#tblItem tr').each(function (i, elem) {
        $(elem).children('td').eq(-1).text('OK');
    });
});
```

Listens for the click event on the button and iterates over all rows of the table. Sets the text of the last table cell for each row to 'OK'.

Comment: what does `elem` mean in your code? Btw, thanks for the reply

Comment: And does that `eq` means the column index? So in my case, should it be `eq(4)`?

Comment: And also, how do I make it dynamic that I need to specify the column index instead of looking always for the last table cell column?

Comment: ```elem``` is a reference to the DOM element. It needs to be wrapped with the jQuery function to make it a jQuery object. ```eq``` selects the jQuery object at the specified index; -1 means the last object. You can just provide a positive number if you want it to be a specific index, but remember 0 is the first index, 1 is the second etc...